# WPF Datagrid row Index always is 0

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to get current editing row index , but it will keep on return 0, I think is because the grid is not visualize yet , so I create a dispatcher to run the code , but still not working

Following is  my Code

```
private void grdUser_RowEditingEnd(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e )
{
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
        {                
            int currentRowIndex = this.grdUser.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(this.grdUser.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(this.grdUser.CurrentItem));
            MessageBox.Show(currentRowIndex.ToString());

        }));
}
```

Is that Other way to get the edited row index ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eventargs and using that you can get index. You can refer the below code.

```
private void grdUser_RowEditingEnd(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(() =>
        {
            int currentRowIndex = this.grdUser.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(e.Row);
            MessageBox.Show(currentRowIndex.ToString());

        }));            
    }
```